# how to put pictures in a row bootstrap

Tags: html, image

I'm trying to get these 3 pictures in a row with no or little spaces in between, but this code is causing them to stack on top of each other.  I also want them to be aligned to the center of the page.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-xs-2">
  <img style= "width: 25%; height: 25%" src="https://image.ibb.co/ckA7ka/mr_marbles.png" alt="Mister Marbles head tilt">
</div>  
<div class="row col-xs-2">
  <img style= "width: 25%; height: 25%"  src="https://image.ibb.co/bTMKyv/kermit.png" alt="Kermit the Dog">
</div>
<div class="row col-xs-2">
  <img style= "width: 25%; height: 25%" src="https://image.ibb.co/ki8tQa/peach.png" alt="Peach posing magestically">  
</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your code or what you want to code

Comment: Not sure what happened, but it's there now.

Comment: please go through https://jsfiddle.net/n1bbjgx8/

Comment: I would like to clarify that a row is a horizontal entity. Multiple rows are positioned on top of each other where as columns are side-by-side and seeing how you mixed the `row` and `col` classes I would expect weird behavior seeing how it can't be both at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks a ton!  It seems like adding the multiple types of columns was the biggest thing.

Comment: @RachaelTanis :)

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this..

dont put class row on every col..

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
  <img style="width: 25%; height: 25%" src="https://image.ibb.co/ckA7ka/mr_marbles.png" alt="Mister Marbles head tilt">
</div>  
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <img style="width: 25%; height: 25%" src="https://image.ibb.co/bTMKyv/kermit.png" alt="Kermit the Dog">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
  <img style="width: 25%; height: 25%" src="https://image.ibb.co/ki8tQa/peach.png" alt="Peach posing magestically">  
</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

[sample code](http://www.bootply.com/jpB8PI95ax)

Comment: I just realized I left that in there when messing around with it.  I had it the way yours is originally but they're still just coming out one on top of the other except now really squished up.

Comment: I forgot to remove the spacing of the images

Answer (score 0):

```
    **YOu need to put everthing in row then add one div with a class .center make the div center finally offset the the first column**  
    ==============================================================


<style>
    /*CENTER COLUMN */
    .align-center {
        text-align: center;
    }
    /*CENTER DIV*/
    .center {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="center">
            <div class="col-xs-2 align-center col-xs-offset-3"> <img style="width: 25%; height: 25%" src="https://image.ibb.co/ckA7ka/mr_marbles.png" alt="Mister Marbles head tilt"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 align-center"> <img style="width: 25%; height: 25%" src="https://image.ibb.co/bTMKyv/kermit.png" alt="Kermit the Dog"> </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 align-center"> <img style="width: 25%; height: 25%" src="https://image.ibb.co/ki8tQa/peach.png" alt="Peach posing magestically"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img style= "width: 25%; height: 25%"  src="webfina/2.png" alt="Kermit the Dog">

<img style= "width: 25%; height: 25%" src="webfina/3.png" alt="Peach posing magestically">
```

Comment: Please add some details or comments in to the code, Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.